# Killing vector fields for $ds^2=\frac{1}{x^2}(dx^2-dy^2)$

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose I have this metric:

$$
ds^2 = \frac{1}{x^2}(dx^2-dy^2)
$$

I want to find its Killing vector fields. By inspection, I see the metric possesses the isometry $y\to y+\text{constant}$, so I can immediately write the following Killing vector:

$$
\xi = (0,1)
$$

However, if I then use the Killing equation $\nabla_i \xi_j + \nabla_j \xi_i = 0 $, I get the following set of differential equations:

$$
\begin{align*}
\partial_x \xi_x + \frac{1}{x}\xi_x=0 \\
\partial_y \xi_y + \frac{1}{x}\xi_x=0 \\
\partial_x \xi_y+\partial_y\xi_x+\frac{2}{x}\xi_y = 0
\end{align*}
$$

The Killing vector $(0,1)$ I found by inspection satisfies the first two equations, but not the last. This is impossible.

I've checked whether the differential equations are correct using the xCoba package to calculate the covariant derivatives and indeed they are. So I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: There are three Killing vectors for this metric. Did you find them all? Hint: $x \partial_x + y \partial y$ is another one, in addition to the one in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh god I forgot $\xi = (0,1)$ is the *contravariant* Killing vector. For the Killing equation, I need the *covariant*, which would be $(0,-1/\tau^2)$. That's embarrassing.